# Where Clause for a datetime Format Not Cooperating

Tags: sql, date, datetime, date-range

I am having an issue working with a date range in our DB. The organic format is datetime "**yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000**". I have tried working with this a few ways and I am not having any success, those methods were:

1. Organic as noted above:

   ```
   Select
   I.InvoiceDate
   ....
   Where I.InvoiceDate >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000'
   ```
2. And converting to a mm/dd/yyy in the select with the where clause as:

   ```
   Select
   Convert(Char(10),I.InvoiceDate,101) as 'InvDt'
   ...
   Where Year(Convert(Char(10),I.InvoiceDate,101)) >= '2017'
   ```
3. Also using the organic field name rather than the convert for the where clause:

   ```
   Select
   Convert(Char(10),I.InvoiceDate,101) as 'InvDt'
   ...
   Where I.InvoiceDate >= '10/01/2017'
   ```
4. Lastly, I also tried picking out the year and/or month using the appropriate year/month tags in the select and/or where clause.

In each instance the same results were produced:
[Results I get AND the organic datetime format before converting to mm/dd/yyyy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ltUM.png)

Thanks for the help good people.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I get the where clause to filter as specified based on the date.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Dag...sorry. I am using MS SQL Server Mgmt Studio 17.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

select

*
 from tableName

where Create_Date >='2017-11-08 00:00:00.000'

Comment: :facepalm: Really....it was the spacing!? I didn't even think to try that since other fields were working w/ the spacing. Thank you good sir.

Comment: brother your first is right, 
could you tel me please exactly what's you want's i mean question

Comment: The provided solution worked, maybe it was me w/ fat fingers last night or not but when I removed the spacing I got the correct results.

I cannot explain it, but when I changed the coding to ... InvoiceDate>='2017-01-01 00:00:00.000' from ... InvoiceDate >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000' it worked.